# How to merge multiple tables of large number of columns with same schemas in Python using sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have multiple tables that all look like this:

```
| Col 1 | Col 2 | ... | col 50 |
| ----- | ----- | --- | ------ |
| 1st   | row   | ... | value  |
| 2nd   | row   | ... | value  |
```

I would like the join (or merge) them to one single table using Python.

### Problem

The number of tables is unknown because it depends on how many files users upload.

There are too many columns (50 of them) to manually write SQL statements.

I was wondering if there's anyway to merge these tables in Python?

I have access to all table names in an array `table_names`, if that's helpful.

Comment: Do you want to get to having a single table in sqlite, or you want to query all the tables individually in Python?  Or something else?  Please [edit] your question to clarify what you want to do, and why you want to do it.  At first glance, it looks as if you want a database design that doesn't create a new table for every file upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up writing a helper function that returns a string to be passed to the cursor for execution:

```py
def merge(table_names, c):
    """ 
    Merge all tables in argument and save the result to a new table 'Merged'.
    
    :param table_names: an array of tables names
    :type table_names: array
    :param c: a cursor to the database
    :type c: Cursor
    """
    if not len(table_names): return
    
    command ="""CREATE TABLE Merged AS\n"""

    for i in range(0, len(table_names)):
        command += "SELECT * FROM {}\n".format(table_names[i])
        if (i != len(table_names) - 1): command += "UNION ALL\n"
    
    c.executescript(command)
```